# get an option list where the cursor is according to what the user has typed in text area

Tags: html

I am making a word prediction software. I have a text area. I want that as the user types something in that text area, an option list should appear on that cursor, the option list should contain all the predictions.
I just want to know how that option list can appear near the cursor in text area.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete functionality on a textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518442/autocomplete-functionality-on-a-textarea)

Comment: Sir, I want a option list on cursor and not a autocomplete beloew text area.

Answer (score 1):

this can be accomplished using [Jquery AutoComplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), but you will need to save all the words to be predicted (may be in json format for example) or use a server-side function

Comment: but autocomplete is a feature of text box. but i want text area.

Comment: sir when we press right click we get an option list. I want the same option list with the prediction words inside it , on the point where the cursor is currently placed. As the user types option list goen on moving further.

Comment: Yes, this is just a demonstration to show that it works, http://jsfiddle.net/mohamed_badr/qgvegdzc/ this is an example with a list

Comment: in your comment you mentioned "right click", in this case, this will not be a prediction I think it will be better to capture and `oncontextmeu`

Comment: sir right click is an eaxmple. i am using ajax for dynamic behaviour. as i type "t" then a option list should appear showing tap,tell, text, telephone.. then as i type "te" option list shoud show, tell, text, telephone...

Comment: i dont want autocomplete.i want list